# How to set readonly to a datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have following html table layout:

```
<table id="mytable">
<tbody>
<tr><td rowspan="2">Row text</td><td><input type="text" value="" readonly /></td><td><input type="text" value="" readonly /></td><td><input type="text" value="" readonly /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" value="" /></td><td><input type="text" value="" /></td><td><input type="text" value="" /></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery `datepicker` is attached with every input fields the table row but all the input fields of first row are readonly. Now when a user selects any date from second row it will add 30days to the selected date and put it to the respective input field of first row by jQuery as below:

```
$('table#mytable > tbody> tr > td > input[type="text"]').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
       yearRange: '1900:2016',
        onClose: function (){
           var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr');
           var thisCell = $(this).closest('td').index();
           var thisDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
           thisDate.setDate(thisDate.getDate() + 30);
          thisRow.prev().find('td:eq(' + (thisCell + 1) + ') input[type="text"]').datepicker('setDate', thisDate);
        });
});
```

I am facing two problems here:

1) I want to set datepicker of input of first row in a way so that it will not open the datepicker on click (It will only be used to display the date+30days which is selected from the second row). i.e. datepickers of first row will be readonly.

2) Whether my above code

```
thisRow.prev().find('td:eq(' + (thisCell + 1) + ') input[type="text"]').datepicker('setDate', thisDate);
```

is effective for adding 30 days to the selected date and display that date in respective input field of first row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$("#datepicker").datepicker(

//

).attr('readonly','readonly');

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker('disable');
```

where `.datepicker` is the class of the datepicker.

Comment: Okay, Thanks, it resolved my first issue. But the second [(2)] is still pending. The selected date+30days is not appearing on respective cell of the first row. I think my selector is not correct. Please help in that issue too.

Answer (score 1):

For Addition of 30 days to selected date, you can try following code.

```
 $('table#mytable > tbody> tr > td > input[type="text"]').datepicker({
        onClose: function(selectedDate, inst) { 
        var d =new Date(selectedDate);
        var day=d.getDate();
        var month=d.getMonth();
        var year=d.getFullYear();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate',new Date(year,month,day+30) );
        }
  });
```

Hope This will help you.